# Convert c# regex to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a field for which I validate against three different user input validation. I have done it on the server side C#, but I need to do it in Jquery/Javascript as well since these text boxes are in a dialog box on the page:

```
if (part.RevisionNumber != null)
            {
                bool isPartRevNA = false;

                //Check if Revision Number = NA or N\A
                if(part.RevisionNumber == "NA" || part.RevisionNumber == @"N\A")
                    isPartRevNA = true;

                if (part.RevisionNumber.Length > 4)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Revision# is an optional field but the format must be :3-digit, numeric values only (e.g., ‘102’) or 2. 4-digit, 3 numeric values plus 1 alpha (e.g., ‘102B’) or 3. Character string to represent not applicable (e.g., ‘NA’, or ‘N/A’). ");
                    isPartRevNA = false;
                }
                if (!isPartRevNA)
                {
                    //revision number not na or n\a
                    //1. check next regex condition of if 3 digit numeric value
                    if (part.RevisionNumber.Length == 3)
                    {
                        string pattern = @"\A(\d){3}\Z";
                        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                        bool match = rgx.IsMatch(part.RevisionNumber);
                        if (!match)
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Revision# is an optional field but the format must be :3-digit, numeric values only (e.g., ‘102’) or 2. 4-digit, 3 numeric values plus 1 alpha (e.g., ‘102B’) or 3. Character string to represent not applicable (e.g., ‘NA’, or ‘N/A’). ");
                    }

                    //2. check regex condition if length 4 
                    if (part.RevisionNumber.Length == 4)
                    {
                        string pattern = @"\d{3}[A-Za-z]";
                        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                        bool match = rgx.IsMatch(part.RevisionNumber);
                        if (!match)
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Revision# is an optional field but the format must be :3-digit, numeric values only (e.g., ‘102’) or 2. 4-digit, 3 numeric values plus 1 alpha (e.g., ‘102B’) or 3. Character string to represent not applicable (e.g., ‘NA’, or ‘N/A’). ");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The field is optional but in the following event I will catch the user input on textarea focus out event, if it has a value and does not meet the user criteria then I will reset the value and alert the user to correct input should they choose to:

1) It could be NA or N\A
2) 3-digit, numeric values only (e.g., ‘102’), @"\A(\d){3}\Z";
3) 4-digit, 3 numeric values plus 1 alpha (e.g., ‘102B’) @"\d{3}[A-Za-z]";

```
$(".foo").focusout( function() {


                alert( $(this).val() );
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the job on its own, and will work in .NET and JS:

```
^(?:N\\?A|\d{3}[A-Za-z]?)$
```

It's pretty simple:

- Either match `N` and `A`, with an optional `\` in between
- Or 3 digits followed by an optional letter.